# Why does Little Mac's coach say "Just like old times, eh?" at his victory screen in Smash Ultimate?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

When you win a game as Little Mac in *Super Smash Bros. Ultimate*, at the victory screen afterwards there is a black man with a towel draped over his neck standing behind Mac who says "Just like old times, eh?"

Who is this and what is the backstory? In the original franchise lore did he and Little Mac grow up together or something? Little Mac doesn't look older than 20s/30s, so what could "old times" be referring to other than their childhood?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The trainer in question is **Doc Louis**. In **(Mike Tyson's) Punch-Out!!** for the NES and **Punch-Out!!** for the Nintendo Wii he is Mac's trainer. He is absent in the SNES game **Super Punch-Out!!**
Timeline wise **Super Punch-Out!!** is set most recently.

Doc's expression is probably a reference to their time as a boxing team with him coaching Mac.

As a sidenote Mac was 17 in the NES game.

Comment: Oh so "old times" wasn't something they referenced in the original game, as in something that took place before the original game, but rather it's a present day reference to the original games from 30 and 40 years ago as the old times. That makes sense.

Comment: I hear he has a penchant for stealing people's bikes, though...